# Is my server drive on SATA2 or SATA3 based on this output?

Tags: linux, centos, performance, hard-drive, sata

`smartctl` output:

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep SATA
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
```

`dmesg` output (empty):

```
# dmesg | grep SATA
```

`hdparm` output:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep SATA
Transport:  Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
```

For some reason there was no output for `dmesg | grep SATA`. I am on CentOS 7 x64.

The specification of SATA 3.1 means SATA3. However, it's confusing because it also says `current: 3.0 Gb/s`. I'm not sure what I'm on or what I'm getting.

Perhaps this is saying that it's a SATA3 drive but plugged into a SATA2 port? I'm having the datacenter check which port it's physically plugged into, my server is new and has two SATA3 ports.

Does this output indicate with any certainty that my hard drive is plugged into a SATA3 port? If so, why am I only getting 3.0gbps according to the output, and how do I fix it?

Comment: To find out what you've got for connection you need to look at two things the drive and the interface. The drive is showing that it is Sata3 compatible. You need to look at what your interface is capable of on the motherboard. The lower of the two is what the drive speed will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `(current: 3.0 Gb/s)` really meant it was on a SATA2 port, because when I switched the drive to be on a SATA3 port, now it reads:

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep SATA
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
```